# Delphi xe com Tcomport

Tags: delphi

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em Delphi usando o Tcomport pela serial com leitor rfid, a tcomport lê as tags e joga ela para dentro componente.

Queria saber se há forma de ligar direto ex; a tcom para aparecer a leitura da tag dentro de um edit, para não precisar de digitar os códigos das tags.

Desde já agradeço

abs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow em Português!  Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está percetível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).